# Avoid MySQL storing null and whitspace data

Tags: php, mysql, database

how to avoid mysql doing this (by itself or php script) , even if only one cell of a row is null or whitspaced like this: `' '`.

we use regular way inserting data:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `rows` (`results1`, `results2`) VALUES ('$res1', '$res2')";
 $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
```

Comment: Not storing nulls is easy - just make the field `NOT NULL`. Whitespace - that one is something you'll have to do pre-insert, or have a trigger to trap the insert and disallow it if there is only whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check it in PHP before sending the data.
2. Mark the columns of the table as `NOT NULL` and while inserting use the `TRIM()` function.

Comment: any NOT NULL field or mark found in fields settings.. there is only a markable NULL inpute.

Comment: do you mean such this? : [link](http://www.davidtan.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/mysql-edit-table-column-properties-not-null-default.jpg)
we only have a checkmark box on null field and not checked.

Comment: Yes. If you are using MySQL workbench the you have to check the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

try the below.
// $res is your value which you get as user input or something else.

```
if(empty($res))
    {
    $error[] = "not able to send as value is null";
    }
```

use array if you have multiple values.
and now

```
 if(empty($error))
    {
$var = trim($res);
    // your insert code.
    }
```

this will surely help you to avoid whitespace and null.

Answer (score 0):

Check your data before you execute your insert query, and quote your values before using them in a query or use placeholders, since you're vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: try `if (!is_null($res) && strlen(trim($res)))`

Answer (score 0):

for avoid `NULL`s you can specify `NOT NULL` directive

Answer (score 0):

```
$r1= trim($res1);
$r2= trim($res2);

if ($r1 ==''||$r2 ==''){

echo 'its null or whitespace';

} else {

 $sql = "INSERT INTO `rows` (`results1`, `results2`) VALUES ('$r1', '$r2')"; 
 $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql); 

}
```

its worked.